# Insert a list in the beginning of a nested list

Tags: python, list, insert, nested-lists

I have two list. One is a list of lists, and the other is a standard list. I need to combine them in such a way as to feed to proper format to the Google Sheets API which needs a list of lists.

```
a =[['079872', 'OE', '02', 'BG', 'K'], ['159926', 'UN', '42', 'DB', 'K'], ['159844', 'UN', '24', 'DB', 'V']]

b = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4', 'col5']

c = a + b
```

`c` Yields:

```
['col1', col2','col3','col4', 'col5'
['079872', 'OE', '02', 'BG', 'K'],
['159926', 'UN', '42', 'DB', 'K'],
['159844', 'UN', '24', 'DB', 'V']]
```

What I need is:

```
[['col1', col2','col3','col4', 'col5'],
['079872', 'OE', '02', 'BG', 'K'],
['159926', 'UN', '42', 'DB', 'K'],
['159844', 'UN', '24', 'DB', 'V']]
```

I've tried all of the solutions that I could find in SO but cannot get to the list of lists that I need. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple solution would also work:

```
>>> [b] + a
 [['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
 ['079872', 'OE', '02', 'BG', 'K'],
 ['159926', 'UN', '42', 'DB', 'K'],
 ['159844', 'UN', '24', 'DB', 'V']]
```

Comment: Note that this isn't inplace, so you will need to assign the result back to `a`.

Comment: Noted. `a = [b] + a` would work just fine if you must persist the change, but the result can also be passed down the pipeline to whatever needs it in this format.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is python, you are looking for `list.insert(0, ...)`:

```
In [336]: a.insert(0, b)

In [337]: a
Out[337]: 
[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
 ['079872', 'OE', '02', 'BG', 'K'],
 ['159926', 'UN', '42', 'DB', 'K'],
 ['159844', 'UN', '24', 'DB', 'V']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `deque` from collections:

```
from collections import deque
a =[['079872', 'OE', '02', 'BG', 'K'], ['159926', 'UN', '42', 'DB', 'K'], ['159844', 'UN', '24', 'DB', 'V']]

b = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4', 'col5']
final = deque(a).appendleft(b)

print(list(d))
```

Output:

```
[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'], ['079872', 'OE', '02', 'BG', 'K'], ['159926', 'UN', '42', 'DB', 'K'], ['159844', 'UN', '24', 'DB', 'V']]
```

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted them all since they all work great.